# My Linux box cannot access other devices on the LAN

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi, lan

I have new mini PC (ASUS) with UBUNTU 21.10
it has an Intel network controller (WiFi 6 Ax200)

I can access the internet and I can see other devices such as my laptop and NAS on the LAN but I cannot access them, i.e., open a directory.

In "Files" " | "Other Locations" are listed: - MyMacBook with remote login and file sharing; - RASPBERRYPI (Samba - updated); and - Windows Network

When I click on them I get the following error messages

MyMacBook (Remote Login) -

```
Unable to access location
"No route to host"
```

MyMacBook (File Sharing) & RASPBERRYPI

```
Unable to access location
 "Failed to retrieve share list from server: No route to host"
```

Windows Network

```
Unable to access location
 "Failed to retrieve share list from server: No such file or directory"
```

my **laptop** does not have problems, e.g., it can readily access the NAS.

I only "problem" that I can find is that the Intel driver is not the one recommended by Intel - they recommend:

- iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode but
- iwlwifi-cc-a0-63.ucode is being loaded
  (the iwlwifi.ko file requests the iwlwifi...63.ucode file)
  (both files are in /lib/firmware)

`dmesg | grep iwl` output verifies that the file: iwlwifi-cc-a0-63.ucode (the incorrect one) is loaded and gives an error:

> "api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver".

could it be the driver that is the problem? if so, can I edit the iwlwifi.ko file and change the 63 to 46?

But some have suggested that the error messages cannot result from a driver problem.

Could it be a hardware problem?

Any suggestions of how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated (please articulate - it has been 40-45 years since I last used UNIX and I am stumbling a bit getting back into it :-)

Comment: Are your servers (Samba (file server), VNC, TinyVNC, etc) updated?

Comment: There is a contradiction between your question title and the line "it can readily access the NAS". I don't think this has anything to do with Intel drivers. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1398821/edit) and add the commands along with the errors in your question. That is, copy the commands and errors from your terminal and paste directly into your question above. Then format the pasted text as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit question window.